# sliding div horizontal using overflow:hidden

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

This can't be harder than I think, but I have run into a dead end and need to get back on track. New to coding, and know this can't be that hard to figure out, but with my current coding knowledge I am just doing trial and error and going in circles. So I have come hear as my last resort, I do not want to affect my rating on here and get banned, so I will try to explain this the best I can...

Simply: (Website link: http://missionaryenterprises.com/home.html) The content part of this page is made up of 9 boxes in an un-ordered list. I need to add more boxes for the content, but without disturbing the size and look of the website, I want to add two buttons on either side that when clicked 9 more content boxes will slide in and appear. I understand I need to create a div that is very wide to hold another set of 9 content boxes, or as many as I want. That div needs have the attribute overflow:hidden, that's about all I know, I am going to play around more, but any help would be much appreciated :) Shalom :)

Comment: Greetings, did you try to look for bootstrap carousel? This is not an answer so take this as a suggestion, but I know this can be helpful to you because as you said "New to coding, and know this can't be that hard to figure out". Bootstrap is a good front end when it comes to website. Link is here http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the show and hide feature of jquery as shown in api.jquery.com

Your html

```
<button id="showr">Show</button>
<button id="hidr">Hide</button>
<li><a href="#"><img src="" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="" /></a></li>
```

and your script:

```
$( "#showr" ).click(function() {
 $( "li" ).first().show( "fast", function showNext() {
   $( this ).next( "li" ).show( "fast", showNext );
  });
});

$( "#hidr" ).click(function() {
 $( "div" ).hide( 1000 );
});
```

Comment: interesting...tried the code I can hide the content but the show button is not working, thought I want more of a carousel, so when the click the left arrow button, the content moves and new content comes in and so on, just like an image slider :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't like JQuery, so i'll explain how I would do it.

First of all, note my fiddle at the end. I re-structured the page. You will have to use CSS to properly display the images on a 3x3 grid, or use a table. Probably easier to use tables, but you have more flexibility with CSS. I hope I'm stressing the separate uses of the trio. It makes things alot easier and cleaner.

Okay, so how I did it is to use JavaScript to swap out the pictures, which circles through an array. You can either name your pictures something like 'img1' to 'img18' (if you have two sets of 9) or just manually put each picture name in the array like I have. Just swap out 'img1',etc. with the URLS of the images (ie. images/img1.png).

```
   var set1 = new Array(
'img1','img2','img3','img4','img5','img6','img7','img8','img9'); 

  var set2 = new Array(
'img1','img2','img3','img4','img5','img6','img7','img8','img9');

  var sets = new Array(set1,set2);
```

Next you have to create a Function to swap out the 9 images with the next 9.
I used a for loop to replace all the images at once.

```
 function change(set) { // Set is sets[0], etc.

   for (var i = 1; i<=set.length; i++) { // 9 images in each set
       var img = document.getElementById("img"+i); // img1, img2, etc.
       img.src = set[i]; //Set img.src to the images in the array
   }
 }
```

Then just pass a set to the function when someone clicks on the forward/back button. I leave it up to you to implement the code to switch the sets. That's the advantage of having the sets array because you can just switch out which set you use.

```
 change(sets[0]);
```

You can just make some buttons or picture links if you want a fancy button (or CSS it up). Then onClick they run the function to swap out the images.

Use CSS for some smooth transitions: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/
Just play around with that until you find the effect you like. To implement it, just set the style using JavaScript upon clicking on a button.

Here's my semi-completed Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/joshlalonde/7Zs7h/6/

Comment: The '9 boxes' = 1 div, they are 9 images in an un-ordered list. So basically I want the people to be able to click a left or right button which scrolls in 9 new images, and so on, so every time they click the  buttons you are scrolling a new set 0f 9 images, its much the same as a single image slider, but I have 9 images in a div and want to add another set of 9 images and most likely another set. Does that explain it? It acts like a carousel :)

Comment: Okay, I finished it. I hope my answer works for you! Good luck. Also, I just pulled a random site for the CSS transitions so you might find a better one. You can use JavaScript for it, too, but I don't imagine that'll make your code look pretty. Plus, I feel like people don't use CSS enough. I also forgot to mention you might want to use Div blocks to quickly do sorcery to make the spacing good for all the images, etc. Good luck!

Comment: Hello Josh, thank you for taking the time to help.. really appreciate it! I have just a couple questions here.. I made up a fiddle where you can see my progress and what I am trying to figure out. Link: http://jsfiddle.net/diffuse20/LQzKS/   When I give the first image an id of "img1" it throws makes my pictures disappear? Also you have two sets in the array, set1 and set2, does set2 need to start at "img10" and so on...?  That's about it, really new a coding here, just pass a set to the function when someone clicks on the forward/back button? If I knew how to do this I would have done it :)

Comment: I by no means want to mooch and appreciate the time you have helped, I have done lots of trial and error working with different techniques but nothing has worked, so here I am.. :) thanks friend!

Comment: Alright. I made the updated, fixed code. I was unclear. Where you see 'img1' and so on, you need to put the link to the image. That is the .src of your image. You leave the src = "" in the HTML because the JavaScript will swap out the images for you. I also made a mistake - array should have started at 0, so I just said i-0. Also I removed the extra lines and condensed it all into one. sorry if that's confusing. http://jsfiddle.net/joshlalonde/LQzKS/2/

Comment: Also on your website, you probably should check out the rotated text. It's going underneath your images. Using IE10 on Windows 8.1 RT for reference.

Comment: Thanks Josh, I really appreciate all your help my friend... I went with another technique, but thank you for you help, and yes I have noticed that, working on fixing that :)